# Query for getting the 3 users with most sales of the day

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I need to retrieve the 3 top users with the most sales from the database. I have this query:

```
Order::select(DB::raw('sum(total_wholesale) as sums'))        
        ->whereDate('created_at', Carbon::today())
        ->orderBy('sums','DESC')        
        ->take(3)
        ->with('seller')
        ->get();
```

But it only returns the sum without the seller relationship. Any ideas on how to get something like this:

```
user1 todays sum
user2 todays sum
user3 todays sum
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course a very simple solution. I was missing the seller_id in the select statement for the with('seller') relationship to work:

```
Order::select('seller_id', DB::raw('sum(total_wholesale) as sums'))        
        ->whereDate('created_at', Carbon::today())
        ->orderBy('sums','DESC')        
        ->take(3)
        ->groupBy('seller_id')
        ->with('seller')
        ->get();
```